# static and reinterpret casting - defined behavior?

Tags: c++

First off, I come from a "managed" land, so be gently. I'm trying to create a messaging system and before I put too much effort into it, I want to make sure my understanding of casting is correct.

Say I have a pod type called header and place that header into another pod type message, can I safely static_cast the message to header and reinterpret_cast the header pointer to a message pointer?

If I understand correctly, casting to the first member of a pod is safe, and reinterpret cast should be safe for returning to my original pointer?

example:

```
struct Header
{
    int m_size;
    int m_type;
};

struct Message
{
    // first member to static cast to..
    Header m_header;
};

// 
int main()
{
    Message msg;
    // cast to the first member, the header.
    auto* hdr = static_cast<Header*>(&msg.m_header);
    // because I know the message by type, safely cast it back to the original message type.
    Message* tmp = reinterpret_cast<Message*>(hdr);
    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you added just a toy example of what it is you want to do.

Comment: Yeah - there's a bunch of unspecified behavior there (not undefined, IIRC -- which means it must have a meaning, but the standard doesn't say what).  Check your compiler documentation.  For the vast majority of compilers, this'll be totally fine.  Note that casting to another type pointer and then *back* to the original is allowed by the standard (5.2.10/7) as long as the 2nd type has a not-stricter alignment requirement.

Comment: 5.2.10/7 "An object pointer can be explicitly converted to an object pointer of a different type. ... ... Converting a prvalue of type “pointer to T1” to the type “pointer to T2” (where T1 and T2 are object types and where the alignment requirements of T2 are no stricter than those of T1) and back to its original type yields the original pointer value. The result of any other such pointer conversion is unspecified."

Comment: @Tumbleweed53 Please post this as an answer.

Comment: @Tumbleweed53 Not always! http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#basic.compound-4 What version of the standard did your quote come from? I don't remember when this change was made.

Comment: What you'll find are there are significant differences between "probably going to work" and "guaranteed to work." As things go by we've seen a trend towards tightening up some rules to allow loosening others. For example, the newer guarantees in what used to be called POD types allowed the rule changes HTNW linked above.

Comment: @user4581301 So based on the link my usage should be fine? I noticed that the pointers are interconvertible for casting to the first member of a standard layout class, which means casting back with reinterpret_cast should yield a valid pointer, assuming the alignments are correct, right?

Comment: In general, `static_cast` and `dynamic_cast` is always safe, but `reinterpret_cast` and `const_cast` almost always mean the code is not safe.

Comment: @MooingDuck "Always safe" is kind of an overstatement. There are many cases where static cast of a pointer/reference is undefined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> can I safely static_cast the message to header

No. Such static cast is ill formed. Similar reinterpret cast would be well defined though... As long as your stated preconditions are true. If you assume them wrongly, then behaviour of the program is undefined.

As pointed out in a comment, your code example static casts header pointer to a header pointer which is of course well defined, but not what you asked about.

> and reinterpret_cast the header pointer to a message pointer?

Yes.

Comment: The code example uses `static_cast<Header *>` on a `Header *` which is well-defined . Maybe OP's example is at odds with their choice of words

Comment: @eerorika I took a closer look at static_cast in my particular use case and I don't understand why it's ill formed. From what I've read both static_cast and reinterpret_cast have the same guarantee in relation to the first member of a standard layout type. If it's not too much trouble, could you elaborate?

Comment: @user3426850 They are unrelated types, so you cannot static cast pointer to one into pointer to another. It's that simple. You've either misunderstood what you've read, or you've read something that's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your optimizer gets confused for some reason, it is best to avoid headaches and call `std::memcpy()`:

```
Message msg;
Header hdr;
std::memcpy(&hdr, &msg, sizeof(hdr));
```

Then you can access the header at your convenience.